SQL Syntax Error After Upgrading Spring Boot to 3.3.4 Using Pageable with DB2
I upgraded my Spring Boot project from version 2.7.18 to 3.3.4. After the upgrade, I started encountering SQL syntax errors when using pagination (Pageable) with DB2 9.5. The issue only occurs when I pass a page number greater than 0 if the page number is 0, the query works fine.
Expected Behavior:
The query should work as expected for any page number in DB2, just like it did in Spring Boot 2.7.18.
Actual Behavior:
With a page number greater than 0, I get the following SQL syntax error from DB2:
2024-10-17 10:17:42,377 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-417, SQLSTATE=42609, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.12.56
2024-10-17 10:17:42,381 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-417;42609;, DRIVER=4.12.56
2024-10-17 10:17:42,393 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [sql code in here] [DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-417, SQLSTATE=42609, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.12.56] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-417, SQLSTATE=42609, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.12.56

Generated SQL (Spring Boot 2.7.18):
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT inner2_.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS rownumber_
        FROM (
            -- Actual query here
        ) AS inner2_) AS inner1_
WHERE  rownumber_ > ?
ORDER  BY rownumber_

Generated SQL (Spring Boot 3.3.4 with Hibernate 6):
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) rn
        FROM ...) r_0_
WHERE  r_0_.rn <= ? + ? AND r_0_.rn > ?
ORDER  BY r_0_.rn

My Repository Interface:
public interface OfferRepository extends CrudRepository<Offer, Integer> {

        @Query(value = "select offer from Offer offer join OrbisListCompany company on offer.companyId = company.companyId "
            + " join OrbisListCompanyPublication companyPub on company.companyId = companyPub.companyId join OfferPublication offerPub on offer.offerId = offerPub.offerId "
            + "where offer.companyId = :companyId and  offer.product.productId = :productId and  company.visible = true and companyPub.publicationId = :pubId and offerPub.publicationId = :pubId  ")
        List<Offer> findByPublicationIdAndCompanyIdAndProductIdAndVisible(@Param("pubId") Integer pubId,@Param("companyId") Integer companyId,@Param("productId") Integer productId,@Param("pageable") Pageable pageable);
}

Integer pageablePage = (Objects.isNull(page) || page == 0 ) ? 0 : page-1;
Integer pageSize = Objects.isNull(size) ? PAGE_SIZE : size;
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageablePage, pageSize)
List<Offer> offers = offerRepo.findByPublicationIdAndCompanyIdAndProductIdAndVisible(pubId, companyId, productId, pageable);

What I have tried:

I attempted to modify the hibernate dialect property to use a custom DB2 dialect based on suggestions from this post, but the issue persists.

I reviewed Hibernate's SQL generation changes in version 6, but couldn't find a fix that works for my setup.



Can you add the full stacktrace?

@M.Deinum I shared it via this link, can you check it?

I hoped it would give some more insight, but it doesn't. Does it work if you do a plain findAll(pageable)? So without a query. Just trying to figure out if it is the dialect or the query generation/wrapping done by Spring Data.

Can you override the SQL to use CAST around the parameter markers? (e.g. cast (? as integer)  , or use bigint if appropriate for rn? ) ?
